# Return array of functions pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I have two files main.c and foo.c, I am trying to copy an array of functions from one file to another.

**My problem is:** Only the first item is getting copied.

This is my code:

**foo.c:**

```
void foo1();
void foo2();
void foo3();
void foo4();
void foo5();
void foo6();
void foo7();

void (*myFuncs[7])() = {
    foo1,
    foo2,
    foo3,
    foo4,
    foo5,
    foo6,
    foo7
};

void* getMyFuncs(){
    return myFuncs;
}
```

**main.c:**

```
void (*things[7])();

void main(){
   memcpy(things, getMyFuncs(), sizeof(getMyFuncs()));
}
```

After running, in debug mode, I inspected my array *things* and only *foo1* pointer has copied.

So, my output has:

```
void (*things[7])() = {
    foo1 (hex address here),
    0x00,
    0x00,
    0x00,
    0x00,
    0x00,
    0x00
};
```

What I expected:

```
void (*things[7])() = {
    foo1 (hex address here),
    foo2 (hex address here),
    foo3 (hex address here),
    foo4 (hex address here),
    foo5 (hex address here),
    foo6 (hex address here),
    foo7 (hex address here)
};
```

Why only the first item is getting copied?

Thanks

Comment: Because you told `memcpy` to only copy one.

Comment: Alternatively: Because you declared `getMyFuncs` with the wrong type, but then `sizeof getMyFuncs()` is still wrong.

Comment: How so? How should I tell to copy all itens?

Comment: What is the result of `sizeof(getMyFuncs())`?

Comment: In debug mode it says that sizeof(getMyFuncs()) returns 0x004

Comment: `getMyFuncs` returns a pointer.  Pointers only know what type they're pointing at (and not even that, for a void*). Even if they are pointing at the first element of an array, they do not know how many elements are in the array.  `sizeof(getMyFuncs()) == sizeof(void*)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was a silly mistake!

My line:

```
memcpy(things, getMyFuncs(), sizeof(getMyFuncs()));
```

is wrong, I don't want to copy the size of getMyFuncs().

The write way to copy is by getting the size of my array of functions:

```
memcpy(things, getMyFuncs(), sizeof(things));
```

Comment: Please accept your answer if you find it useful :).

Comment: Really? Why two days?

Comment: Yes, when I click accept a message popups saying 'You can accept your own answer in 2 days'

Comment: Please see my suggested edit. `sizeof(getMyFuncs)` is different than `sizeof(getMyFuncs())`. The second is the *return value* of `getMyFuncs`.

Comment: @JL2210 `sizeof(getMyFuncs)` is *definitely* not the right answer.  That's just the size of a function pointer.

Comment: Yeah. That's why I said they were entirely different. I just was going for clarification.